# Keyboard shortcut in VS to open Javascript console

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a keyboard shortcut or a way to assign one to open the JavaScript console when debugging IE in Visual Studio. I hate having to go through the menus to get to this, especially since it's kind of buried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!

**Javascript Console Shortcut**

```
Ctrl + Alt + V, C
```

Found this at [visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/)

**Note:** If you are using ReSharper, this shortcut is overridden and will perform ReSharper's `Inspection Results` window.

In Visual Studio, go to 
    `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`

Search for `ReSharper_ShowInspectionWindow` in the `Show commands containing:` box, then select it from the list.

When selected you can select `Remove` which should restore the `JavaScriptConsole` command.

Comment: Thanks! I believe I looked there, but did a search on JavaScript, not Java Script. It's the little things!

Comment: I spoke to soon. This does nothing.

Comment: Make sure you try it while your app is running.  When the Web application isn't running, the JavaScript console is not available.  While running, the console comes up in Visual Studio 2015.  I just did it right now to make sure. :)  Also make sure you press Ctrl + Alt + V first, release the keys, then press C.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I might have misspoken when I said it does nothing. In fact, what it does is say "No inspection results. Use Ctrl+Shift+Alt+A to run an inspection." This is when I press Ctrl+Alt+V. Pressing C thereafter doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sounds like you are having the shortcut overridden by ReSharper.  If this is correct, I've updated the answer with instructions to restore the JavaScriptConsole shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, and with this hint I was able to find Debug.JavaScriptConsole and assign it to something that makes more sense (Ctrl+Alt+J).